# Convert document.stylesheets into array of paths in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom, stylesheet

I have a dynamic bit of code in java-script that analyzes the style-sheets on a page. I've got most parts working, but I am having one hang-up...

A portion where I'm checking for the existence of certain style-sheets. MDN has this to say about it, "[The StyleSheetList] is an array-like object but can't be iterated over using Array methods.  However It can be ... converted to an Array." They include an example where they turn the object into an array of rules, but I don't see a clear way to get path. It also says "styleSheetList[index]" is a way it can be accessed. I tried creating this function, but it doesn't work, always returning false...

```
function checkStyleSheet (styleSheetPath){
    var mysheets=document.styleSheets;
    for (var i = 0, max = mysheets.length; i < max; i++) {
        if (mysheets[i].href == styleSheetPath){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Thanks

**JFiddle**
https://jsfiddle.net/3jsvbwrv/

**Edit:** 
console.log of mysheets[i] just inside the for loop returns...

```
// CSSStyleSheet → http://example.com/example.css
CSSStyleSheet { 
    ownerRule: null,
    cssRules: CSSRuleList[1],
    type: "text/css",
    href: null,
    ownerNode: <style>,
    parentStyleSheet: null,
    title: "",
    media: Object[0],
    disabled: false 
}
```

**Edit 2:** 
Note: Changing mysheets[i].href to just mysheets[i] in the if statement does not resolve the issues. example.css would still be found as false.

**Edit 3:**
I don't feel it should have any impact, but just in case it might be useful, or give a broader overview, or help with context... the CSS scripts that are there are included via this function which is called first (which is verified to work)...

```
function addStyleSheet (styleSheetPath){
    var link = document.createElement("link");
    link.rel = "stylesheet";
    link.href = styleSheetPath;
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(link);
}
```

My end goal is to make this work...

```
function requireStyleSheet (styleSheetPath){
    if (!checkStyleSheet(styleSheetPath)){
        addStyleSheet(styleSheetPath);
    }
}
```

**Edit 4**
My test html:

```
<button onmousedown="addStyleSheet('htt://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css')">Step1‌​</button>
<button onmousedown="requireStyleSheet('http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css')">S‌​tep 2</button>
```

**Edit 5** As some testers noted, the code works as-is. It turns out that my problem is that the called file hadn't finished loading before my second function tried to check for its presence.

Comment: Please trace/log mysheets[i]

Comment: Depending on the particular sheet being itereated over, it returns either 

`CSSStyleSheet → http://example.com/example.css`

or

`CSSStyleSheet { ownerRule: null, cssRules: CSSRuleList[1], type: "text/css", href: null, ownerNode: <style>, parentStyleSheet: null, title: "", media: Object[0], disabled: false }`

However, in either case, it still returns false, which strikes me as odd. Since in the first the address is obviously there, and the latter, it doesn't make sense for there to be a null href.

Comment: Please add this to your post and code format it :) It's just unreadable here

Comment: Thanks.. href is null here so mysheets[i].href == styleSheetPath wouldn't work unless styleSheetPath is null too...

Comment: So the problem is why it's returning href=null when there's obviously an href, and why the first result won't trigger a true either (even if I change mysheets[i].href to mysheets[i]). It's definitely inducing head-scratching on my part. :/

Comment: Just tested that here and it works, href has a value. Please show me your html where you declare your <link href>

Comment: Also tested your addStyleSheet function and everything works as expected here...

Comment: Added above context. Adding via my addStyleSheet fuction (since I can't _really_ use example.com for a css and get results, my test css is http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js.

Comment: Wrong link my friend

Comment: Here's example html for testing...
`<button onmousedown="addStyleSheet('http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js')">Step1</button><button onmousedown="requireStyleSheet('http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js')">Step 2</button>`

Comment: Are you trying to embed .js file in link tag????

Comment: Oh, my bad, you're right, wrong link. I completely missed that. (Have a similar thing going on where I'm doing similar with js scripts but works differently.) My CSS is this. Going back and refactoring previous examples..
http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css

Comment: Please do a fiddle now, this is getting too hard to read in the comments

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I ran the code in my page with a valid CSS file as an argument, it returned `true`. In your example it does appear as though you are trying to load a JS file instead of a CSS file:

```
<button onmousedown="addStyleSheet('http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js')">Step1‌​</button>
<button onmousedown="requireStyleSheet('http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js')">S‌​tep 2</button>
```

Perhaps you might consider having `checkStyleSheet` check a hash instead of looping through each style sheet each time as well.

Comment: What css did you use? I'm beginning to wonder if it's the css being used for some weird reason.

Comment: I just used some css on this stack overflow page itself.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question but it was also the first search result when I came looking for the same thing. Javascript has a few new tricks I guess, since this is what I have working now:

```
[].slice.call(document.styleSheets).map(e => e.href)
```

Comment: That is a pretty smooth-looking solution!